# File attributes on Android (Linux): Any way to make a file fully writable but not deleteable?

Tags: adb, root-access, file-system, linux, storage

I tried `chattr` with the `+a` (`+i` is even more restrictive), but it immediately caused app panic aka "app has stopped". What I want to do is make a file & folder undeletable.

You can perform any kind of `rw` function (add a.k.a. append, delete some data inside, update) but **`rm file/folder` (file deletion) is not allowed until that attribute is reset** so that the app continues to run as normal.

Is that possible or asking for too much? Pardon my lack of surf searching. I'd imagine this to be in the *wish list* of many so it won't harm framing this languishing wish as a question.

Comment: `chattr +a` is what you are looking for. But then the file must always be opened with [`O_APPEND`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html#DESCRIPTION) flag. Obviously you cannot force existing apps and programs to do so. Other options are [ACLs](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfacl.1.html) and SELinux. The latter provides very [fine-grained control](https://selinuxproject.org/page/ObjectClassesPerms#common_file) (over `read`, `write`, `append`, `unlink`, `rename` etc.). But each option has its own pros and cons.

Comment: By the way `a` and `i` attributes are called [Linux filesystem attributes](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html), not [extended attributes](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfattr.1.html).

Comment: @Irfan Yes `+a` is what I meant. I mentioned *-* as in option ( - ) a. For the latter as with other situations - found out that I likely have to recompile kernel with newer rules. If its possible to  simply modify  `SePolicy` on `Android` without `recompile`. If so citing some e.g.'s would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use any fancy ACLs or attributes for this. Just make the file writable and the directory that it's in read-only. This works because deleting a file only checks for write permission on the parent directory, and completely ignores permissions on the file itself.

Comment: If I do that it cannot create new files in that `dir`. I  am talking of an `app` in android